# Principes d'accès aux réponse supprimées

Tags: support, answers, deletion

Je ne savais pas que l'on pouvait faire disparaitre les réponses. Il y avait toujours accès aux réponses supprimées, mais sur la page « [Sens de « ne t'en fais pas d'autres »](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/53301/17649) », il y avait hier une réponse de [s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/26366/s-h-a-r-p-r-i-f-t), et elle a disparu.

Est-ce que la politique de SO a changé tout d'un coup, ou bien existe-t-il un biais dont je ne serais pas conscient ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La réponse n'a pas disparu, @s.H.a.R.p.R.i.F.t l'a postée en tant que [community wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts).

Answer (score 2):

Le fonctionnement du *Community Wiki* est expliqué dans le lien de l'[autre réponse](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/945/26366). Je les utilise pour reproduire un contenu en commentaire comme réponse sans m'approprier les points qui pourraient venir avec lors du vote, simplement parce que je ne suis pas l'auteur. Par ailleurs, ce ne serait pas obligatoire, je peux partager et modifier tout contenu des (questions, discussions en salle) réponses ou des commentaires en respectant les termes de la licence, qui exige l'attribution, et les présenter dans une réponse en mon nom et récolter des points si on vote. Les commentaires sont faits sous la même [licence](https://stackoverflow.com/help/licensing) que tout autre contenu sur le site (« all publicly accessible user contributions are licensed under Creative Commons Attribution-ShareAlike license ») Ici, la réponse a été enrichie et le nom du dernier contributeur apparaît.

[image]

N'importe qui peut faire de sa réponse un Community Wiki en cochant la case en bas à droite de l'interface de réponse...

Answer (score 1):

D'abord les commentaires existent pour poser une question au PO ou pour clarifier la question. Le modèle SE, c'est de donner des réponses au lieu de répondre dans les commentaires ; les réponses existent pour répondre à la question et avec des sources autant que possible. La réponse n'a pas disparu  ; ça a été refait en wiki.

On ne peut pas trouver ce qui est écrit dans les commentaires quand on cherche le site (et bien l'Internet, les moteurs de recherche ne les retrouvent pas). Les commentaires peuvent être effacées comme si ça n'existait pas.  Malheureusement on perd pas mal de contenu comme ça quand les commentaires deviennent une conversation, ça fait dommage.

Quand il y a trop de réponses en commentaire, on peut créer un wiki afin de ne pas perdre les renseignements.  Comme [une autre réponse](https://french.meta.stackexchange.com/a/946/1893) a bien dit, on a aussi le droit de répondre aux questions quand on respecte les termes, tout est CC.BY.SA.

Comment: « ça fait dommage » ne se dit pas : https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%C3%A7a+fait+dommage&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=fr-2019&smoothing=3 Seulement « c'est dommage » (c'est conjugué, bien sûr, c'était, ce serait,…). //  Ce que vous répondez à propos des commentaires est judicieux et un argument puissant pour empêcher les utilisateurs de répondre dans les commentaires, mais ça ne relève pas de la question, et user jlliagre a déjà fait la même réponse. Ce qui n'est pas clair c'est qui peut  transformer une réponse en wiki et comment. (mais +1 pour l'effort et les idées)

Comment: @LPH Désolé de te contredire mais *ça fait dommage* se **dit** ! Je pense que c'est un régionalisme (sud-ouest de la France **au moins**) et peut-être Québec vu le nombre d’occurrences que je viens de trouver en provenance du Québec grâce à un moteur de recherche. Bien sûr un ngram ne sert à rien pour ce genre de recherche, on est dans la langue parlée et qui est aussi employée sur les réseaux sociaux et les forums.  De façon à être rigoureux  tu aurais dû écrire « « ça fait dommage » ne s'écrit pas dans la bonne littérature en dehors de retranscription du langage parlé ».